# Django Rest Framework is owner

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'd like to create a field `is_owner` for my serializer which would return whether or not the object being serialized is owned by the user making the request. Something like:

```
"""Defines Some serializer with an owner"""
from rest_framework import serializers

class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """Returns the is_owner field as a boolean"""
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = ('is_owner',)

 def get_is_owner(self, obj):
    """Will return True if the requesting user is the owner, else false"""
    return request.user.id == obj.user.id
```

Is this the way to do it? Should I be passing the `request` object to the serializer to make this work? Should I be testing this at the view level?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_is_owner(self, obj):
    """
    you can pass request in context
    """
    return self.context['request'].user.id == obj.user.id
```

when you call the `serializer` pass `request` in `context` like following code;

`serializer = SomeSerializer(instance, context={'request': request, ...})`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much.